MOSFET switching with PWM
I have a question about MOSFET switching. I have a 126V voltage source and I want to drive it with a PWM signal. There will be a buck converter at the output of this MOSFET.
What is wrong with this circuit?
PWM signal: 3.3V - 500kHz - %10.15873016 duty cycle
Vsource: 126V


M2 could be reverse-wired ...

oww! Sorry, I fixed it, thanks. I also re-uploaded the image. thank you. Now what should I do about the circuit?

For acceptable rise and fall times @500 kHz you're going to have to push pull drive that gate with a proper gate driver...

Why not use a buck converter that can take 126 V as input?

126v input buck converter IC's are too expensive. Do you know any cheap IC for buck converter?

@Knoples To go from 126V down to say 12V, a buck topology is not the best. That’s why chips are expensive - “nobody” uses them. You’ll need a transformer, and a topology that’s built around that. There are many to choose from, based on the power (watts) level you need.

\$
\def \ohm {\rm\,\Omega}
\def \farad {\rm\,F}
\def \sec {\rm\,s}
\def \usec {\rm\,\mu s}
\def \kHz {\rm\,kHz}
\def \volt {\rm\,V}
\def \amp {\rm\,A}
\def \watt {\rm\,W}
\$

What is the problem with the circuit I am making right now

It would help if you told us why you think there is a problem, and add some graphs to the question to illustrate it.
It's of course possible to imagine what's wrong, though, just based on the schematic.

The NMOS and PMOS devices you chose are meant for chip design. They are not representative of discrete mosfets you'd use in a power supply. So, as a start, you'd want to use real mosfet models, with part numbers you can actually buy.

There is no load on the output of M2, so parasitic capacitances determine what signal you get on the VOUT node. You should add a load - ideally one that's representative of your application.


Get simple things working first: get just a PWM source of proper amplitude, and have it drive the switching transistor directly. Put a load on the output of the switch. See that it switches.
Then add some series resistance between the PWM source and the gate of the switch. Experiment to understand how the value of that resistance affects performance. You'll quickly see that a 10kΩ source resistance (that's what the R2 pullup was!) is orders of magnitude too high to drive a power mosfet gate.
As a rule of thumb, assume that the gate capacitance of a power mosfet is 1nF. It may be say 0.5nF, or 5nF - what's important is the order of magnitude. Not think of the time constant of this capacitance combined with a 10kΩ source impedance:
$$\tau = R \cdot C = 10^4\ohm \cdot 10^{-9}\farad = 10^{-5}\sec = 10\usec = (100\kHz)^{-1}$$
That time constant would be acceptable for 10kHz operation at a reasonable efficiency, even though even then it's not ideal. Typically you'd want to be at least an order of magnitude (10x) slower than the time constant when driving a square wave.
Concretely, here are the circuits you should get to work, in order:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The LOAD resistor has to be sized according to your expected load current. For an initial circuit, you could set LOAD=126Ω so that just 1A peak flows through the load.
The first circuit applies the drive signal exactly where you want it: between the gate and the source of the P-MOSFET. You'll find that Rs1 needs to be well below 1kΩ to get it to switch the output at 500kHz.
If you have a way of powering the PWM source in circuit 1 in real life, then that's all you'd need for a practical circuit.
Usually, though, the PWM waveform may be sourced by some chip that's ground-referenced. In that case, there needs to be a large DC offset applied to it, so that the signal at G1 and G2 is identical. If V3/offset was 0V, G2 would be close to zero, and M2 would be destroyed since the gate-source voltage would be way past the maximum rating of M2. To be safe, assume that the G-S voltage has to be wihin a ±15V range for high voltage mosfets.
The level shifting for the gate of the PMOS can be achieved by using a PWM current source, and a resistor to convert that current back to voltage:

simulate this circuit
The circuit on the left is a block diagram. The circuit on the right is a minimal practical implementation. Ri2 converts the voltage on V2 to current. Q1-Q2 is a current mirror that copies the Ri2 current to Rs2.
Q1 and Q2 should be the same type, and they need to have the V(CE)max rating 2-3x higher than VCC, i.e. 250V-400V in your case of 125V supply.
To get 500kHz square wave into the gate, the time constant of the gate RC circuit needs to be say 0.1μs. That means Rs≈100Ω. To get a 15V swing across 100Ω we need
$$ I_{PP} = \frac{V_{PP}}{R} = \frac{15\volt_{PP}}{100\ohm} = 0.15\amp_{PP}, $$ where PP means peak-to-peak.
So, the current source needs to drive a 150mA square current waveform into Rs. The maximum possible heat dissipation on Rs would be
$$ P_{Rs,\max} = V\cdot I = 15\volt \cdot 0.15\amp = 2.3\watt. $$ Rs needs to be a pretty hefty resistor to dissipate that much power.
Q2 will need to dissipate a lot of power too - about
$$ P_{Q2\,max} = (V_{CC}-V_{PP})\cdot I = (125\volt-15\volt)\cdot0.15\amp = 17\watt. $$ That's not very practical. So we can add a series heat dissipating resistor RQ between the gate and Q2 to dissipate some of the heat. We want 110V drop across that resistor when 0.15A flows through it, so
$$ R_Q = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{110\volt}{0.15\amp} \approx 700\ohm. $$
Now Q2 gets to dissipate less power, since it's mostly fully switched on and off.

simulate this circuit
Rq has to be a 20W non-inductive resistor, so in practice that means say 10 paralleled 2W surface mount resistors on a heat-dissipating substrate e.g. aluminum. Not very practical, but at least we're getting somewhere. Things are hot, but they are now close to working the way we want.
We had to adjust Rq so that Q2 would go close to saturation, i.e. the collector voltage swings down to about 1V when Q2 is on. That way, the dissipation on Q2 is kept below 1W:

The load doesn't switch very fast, because Rs is still too large - but at least it keeps up with the 500kHz rate:

When we look at the gate voltage, we get to see why the load doesn't switch fast. There's a capacitve coupling between the ramp on M1's drain and its gate that keeps the gate voltage at a plateu, keeping M1 turned on far longer than we want:

The plateau is between the two green vertical lines. This waveform should be a square wave!
We can now add an emitter follower between the Rs-Rq connection point and the gate of M1. We can then lower the current amplitude through the current source from 150mAp-p to 10mAp-p. That way, the current source dissipates over an order of magnitude less heat.
To prevent Q4 from excessive peak heat dissipation (20W+!), we use Re. In practice, we'd need several Q4's in parallel, each with their own Re, or a single transistor that could dissipate the peak heating we throw at it.

simulate this circuit
M1 turn-off is now 3x faster than it was before:

But M1's gate current is not very symmetric for the turn-on and turn-off. This causes extra heat dissipation in the Q3/Q4 buffer.

The cause is the capacitive coupling from M1's drain to gate. We can shunt that current with a Zener diode D1, and further add a speed-up capacitor across Rq:

simulate this circuit
Now M1's gate current is fairly symmetric - very much how we'd like it to be, and how it'd look if a gate driver chip was used. M1's gate current and drain currents are plotted below, together with input current through Ri to visualize the delay between the control waveform from V1 and the output waveform through the load.

Observe how the gate has to be driven with peaks of several hundred mA just to switch M1 quickly! That's the problem that gate driver chips are designed to solve.
The gate of a mosfet can be thought of as a capacitor from gate to drain, and changing its state between ON and OFF requires solid pulses of current.
We could, of course, further refine the discrete gate driver and get even better performance out of it - mostly in terms of the power dissipation. But that is quickly turning into a rather complex job.
For a beginner, I suggest just using an off-the-shelf gate driver with specifications - such as voltage ratings - according to your requirements.
This circuit will not work on a solderless breadboard. It has to be prototyped on a ground plane, Manhattan-style, with precautions against electrocution (!!). This circuit will injure or kill you if you're not careful.
Manhattan style prototyping technique is not new. Here's a contemporary example:

Source: https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/163128/manhattan-and-pittsburgh-electronics-prototyping-techniques

You did an incredible job. I can't thank you enough. Thank you for everything.


What is the problem with the circuit I am making right now, I would be
very happy if you could help me.

When M1 activates, its drain falls to 0 volts and the full 126 volts appears between source and gate of M2. That will destroy it in a fraction of a second.
My advice is use a proper gate driver circuit and, good luck finding one that works efficiently at 500 kHz.

When I give PWM I want to read 126 volts. But when there is no PWM I want it to be 0V. How can I do this? Would using a gate driver be a solution to this? And should I change the frequency? Thank you for your answer.

I have no idea what you mean. Please be clearer in your first 3 sentences. Why are you asking me the 4th sentence and 5th sentence? Basically, the whole of your comment is flawed or undecipherable or unanswerable by me.

I have a pwm signal coming from my MCU. When this signal is there, I want to read 126V at the output. When there is no pwm signal coming from the MCU, I want to read 0V. How can I do this?

You need to convert the PWM signal to an "activate signal" using a monostable (it seems).

thank you for your help.

The following answers is not directly answering your question,but provide you with working alternative path best on my experience.
PMOS is not recommended to be used in high voltage circuit although you can find some components who can stand high voltage.
Why not using a NMOS driver IC to drive a high voltage NMOS transistor - easy ,low cost and ensuring your circuit switch well....
Selecting the right driver for your application   should be best on voltage ,isolation , current , dead time etc.. see application-note in TI ,ST , infinion, sites.

thank you for your help.
